# Logistic regression using GridSearchCV

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, random-forest, logistic-regression, grid-search

I'm trying to find out how to use the linear regression with GridSearchCV, but i get a nasty error, and I don't get if this is a problem of estimator not correct for GridSearchCV or if this is my "LogisticRegression" that is not set correctly. I made it work for random forest and knn, but i'm stuck with this implementation.

I use a small dataset, that's why I want to use the liblinear (even if it is by default as described in the documentation).

```
tuned_parameters = {'C': [0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100]}
clf = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'), tuned_parameters, cv=5, scoring="accuracy")
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and the error:

```
StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, random_state=0, test_size=0.4,
            train_size=None)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "linearRegression.py", line 105, in <module>
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 945, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 564, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 608, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 571, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 109, in apply_async

result = ImmediateResult(func)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 326, in __init__

self.results = batch()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__

return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 260, in _fit_and_score

test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 288, in _score

score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py", line 91, in __call__

y_pred = estimator.predict(X)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 336, in predict

scores = self.decision_function(X)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 320, in decision_function

dense_output=True) + self.intercept_

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 189, in safe_sparse_dot

return fast_dot(a, b)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype([('f0', 'f8'), ('f1','f8')]) to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I read the documentation: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

and

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
Shape of X and Y:

> X = np.array(Xlist,np.dtype('float,float'))  #-> two floats as features
>   y = np.array(ylist,np.dtype('int')) #-> label 0 or 1

example:
X_train is

> [[(0.0, 0.0) (3.85, 0.0)]  [(3.6, 0.0) (2.45, 0.0)]  [(1.1, 0.0)
>   (1.35, 0.0)]  [(3.7, 0.0) (1.85, 0.0)]]

Y_train is

> [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]

Comment: Which version of scikit you are using? What does StratifiedShuffleSplit has to do here?

Comment: I am using last version of scikit learn, 0.18.1.

Comment: I use  StratifiedShuffleSplit to split my data between test and train

Comment: Can you print the shapes of train_X and train_Y and also their dtypes

Comment: I edited the post to print it. Thanks

Comment: What does the tuples represent. The classifiers in scikit dont take input as tuples. They only take 2d arrays of [n_samples, n_features]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140082/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-and-kulssaka).

Comment: I know it doesn't solve your problem, but a does using `LogisticRegressionCV` work? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok a friend of mine solved it:

I was using:

```
X = np.array(Xlist,np.dtype('float,float'))
y = np.array(ylist,np.dtype('int'))
```

and it wouldn't do well with this estimator, even if it was working with these classifiers:

SVC(kernel='rbf'), SVC(kernel='linear'), SVC(kernel='poly'), NeighborsClassifier(), DecisionTreeClassifier(), RandomForestClassifier()

So I just replaced these 2 lines by:

```
X = np.asarray(Xlist)
y = np.asarray(ylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you entered the X data set as a list of tuples: (A,B), instead of a list of arrays:[A,B]?

I was able to run the following code with scikit-learn==0.18.1:

```
## Libraries
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = [[0.0, 0.0], [3.85, 0.0], [3.6, 0.0], [2.45, 0.0], [1.1, 0.0], [1.35, 0.0], [3.7, 0.0], [1.85, 0.0]]
y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

tuned_parameters = {'C': [0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100]}
clf = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'), tuned_parameters, cv=3, scoring="accuracy")
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Note: I had to reduce the cv attribute of GridSearchCV because there isn't a large enough data set to divided into 5 parts.

Comment: I used StratifiedShuffleSplit instead of train_test_split, i will try right away :)

Comment: it didn't work,  a friend of mine solved it though:
I was using:
X = np.array(Xlist,np.dtype('float,float'))
y = np.array(ylist,np.dtype('int')) instead of
X = np.asarray(Xlist)
y = np.asarray(ylist)

Comment: I believe train_test_split is now the preferred method. If I was of assistance, like my response. Otherwise, answer your own question.